# How to set Heroku config var with contents of a file

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

To set config vars for a Heroku app, you do this:

```
$ heroku config:set GITHUB_USERNAME=joesmith
```

How would I set a config var with the contents of a file?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Take a look at the [`heroku-config`](https://github.com/xavdid/heroku-config) plugin, which adds a `heroku config:push` command to push key-value pairs in a file named `.env` to the app.

It also has a `heroku config:pull` command to do the opposite and works very well with [`foreman`](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) for running the app locally with the config in `.env`.

https://github.com/xavdid/heroku-config

###### Example

```
heroku config:push --file=.env.production
```

Comment: How to do it to config vars of pipeline's review apps?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late but still it will be helpful for future users who land here.

I also wanted a quick solution to add variable to heroku app but copy-paste is so boring.. So wrote a script to read values from the `.env` file and set it at the requested app - all things passed as an option:

https://gist.github.com/md-farhan-memon/e90e30cc0d67d0a0cd7779d6adfe62d1

**Usage**

```
./bulk_add_heroku_config_variables.sh -f='/path/to/your/.environment/file' -s='bsc-server-name' -k='YOUR_CONFIG_KEY1 YOUR_CONFIG_KEY2'
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple pure-python solution using honcho and invoke:

```py
from honcho.environ import parse
from invoke import run

def push_env(file='.env'):
    """Push .env key/value pairs to heroku"""
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        env = parse(f.read())
    cmd = 'heroku config:set ' + ' '.join(
        f'{key}={value}' for key, value in env.items())
    run(cmd)
```

The idea here is that you will get the same configuration as if you ran the project locally using honcho. Then I use invoke to run this task easily from the command line (using `@task` and `c.run`) but I've adapted it here to stand alone.